# Accessing sqlite database from Firebase Messaging Service when app in background

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want my app to access sqlite database whenever I receive a message from FirebaseMessagingService ..

```
 final ArrayList<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Album> aa = sqlite_data_helper.getAlbums();
    Log.d("ALBUMSSS", aa.size() + "");
    albums.addAll(aa);
```

This is how I am accessing database from my FirebaseMessagingService

```
public ArrayList<Album> getAlbums() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + ALBUMTABLE, null);
        Log.d("CURSOR", cur.getCount() + " Values");
        ArrayList<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d("GETALBUMS", cur.getCount() + "");
        if(cur != null){
            cur.moveToLast();
            while (cur.isBeforeFirst() == false) {
                Album album = new Album();
                album.setId(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ALBUMID)));
                album.setName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ALBUMNAME)));
                Log.d("GETALBUMS", album.getName());
                album.setNumber_of_images(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(NUMBEROFIMAGES)));
                album.setUnViewedImages(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(NUMBEROFUNVIEWEDIMAGES)));
                cur.moveToPrevious();
                albums.add(album);
            }
            Log.d("GETALBUMS", "Got All Albums");
            cur.close();
            return albums;
        }else {
            cur.close();
            Log.d("GETALBUMS", "Cursor Null");
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("GETALBUMS", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my method to access database in DatabaseHelper class .. But whenever I do so when app is in background `cur.getCount();`returns 0 .. I am aware that if data message is passed then the code runs in background. Rest of the code is working fine just cannot access database when app is in background, when in foreground it is able to access database.

Thanks in advance..